# Подключение к websocket C++

Tags: c++, websocket

Пытаюсь написать бота для `GoodGame`, для этого надо подключиться к `websocket`. Пытался  сделать через `boost::asio`, но ничего не вышло.

Напишите пример кода подключения по адресу: `wss://chat.goodgame.ru/chat/websocket`, с подробными комментарии (Неважно с помощью какой библиотеки).

Моя неудачная и неосмысленная попытка:

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Normal boost::asio setup
    std::string const host = "wss://chat.goodgame.ru/chat/websocket";
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver r(ios);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(ios);
    boost::asio::connect(sock,
                         r.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query{host, "80"}));

    using namespace boost::beast::websocket;
    stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&> ws(sock);
    ws.handshake(host, "/");
    boost::beast::multi_buffer buffer;
    ws.read(buffer);
    std::cout << boost::beast::buffers_to_string(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Предоставьте, пожалуйста, код вашей попытки

Comment: @Alexander Chernin, там нет ничего осмысленного, я просто скопировал код из интернета, пытаясь понять как оно работает.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37078568/3503216

Comment: Вот ваш случай (та же проблема) - подключение к веб-сервису через `asio` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386919/how-to-access-web-service-using-boostasio

Comment: @Alexander Chernin, моя проблема не в том что я не могу подключится, а в том, что я в принципе непониманию как это должно работать. И в следствии этого я и прошу работающий пример подключения с пояснениями. 

Я попытался собрать код под себя из того вопроса, но он не компилируется.

Comment: Есть же нормальный пример на [сайте beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/quick_start.html), с комментариями.